# AngularJS orderby integer field not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I just took the simplest demo from http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy  and just change the value of age to have different number of digit. It stop working as it expected. Its ordering like "string" not as "integer" value. How should i change it so that it order by age like integer value?

Plunkr demo is here
http://plnkr.co/edit/pzgiIYrki7jUZdVaTMt9?p=preview

Codes are:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.friends =
      [{name:'John', phone:'555-1212', age:'2352345'},
       {name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', age:'4235243'},
       {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', age:'241'},
       {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', age:'34325'},
       {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', age:'1234'}]
  $scope.predicate = '-age';
}


<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="App">
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <pre>Sorting predicate = {{predicate}}; reverse = {{reverse}}</pre>
  <hr/>
  [ <a href="" ng-click="predicate=''">unsorted</a> ]
  <table class="friend">
    <tr>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'name'; reverse=false">Name</a>
          (<a href="" ng-click="predicate = '-name'; reverse=false">^</a>)</th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'phone'; reverse=!reverse">Phone Number</a></th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'age'; reverse=!reverse">Age</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i added other answer that will work for you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you have to convert age to type Number to make to `orderBy` to work as it should.

Add to your controller to sort String age as float:

```
   angular.forEach($scope.friends, function (friend) {
    friend.age = parseFloat(friend.age);
   });
```

It should work,

See <kbd>[PLunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JQPEt1IWuAGzb8IR9kDA?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: from your previous answer, i had been googling for how to remove quote or convert to integer too. Found this answer too, this way should be the only solution for now i guess :) ... unless i have a big list and had to foreach through, then it will be bad practise, isn't it :S

Comment: `unless i have a big list and had to foreach through` ,right but you do it only once during compilation. I sorted by integer once 85M json 150k of objects. Took me 4 sec, so no worries

Comment: Try to test it with remove Quotes or convert to Integer with timer

Comment: For numbers like age, which are unlikely to be represented as a float, shouldn't you use `parseInt(friend.age, 10)` instead?

Answer (score 11):

I know is a little late for this answer, but in the newest version of Angular, you can use a function as the orderBy's predicate (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).
In this case, add to the controller a function like next

```
$scope.orderByFunction = function(friend){
    return parseInt(friend.age);
};
```

and change the predicate in the orderBy filter

```
ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:orderByFunction:reverse"
```

This will do the trick!

Comment: adding to the above, In case if this has to be applied in a controller, need to do something like this  array = orderBy($scope.topMacsArray,'parseInt(count, 10)',true); where true means "reverse" the order.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to remove quotes in age variable because it's an integer, not a string:

```
  $scope.friends =
      [{name:'John', phone:'555-1212', age:2352345},
       {name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', age:4235243},
       {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', age:241},
       {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', age:34325},
       {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', age:1234}]
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs have in built functionalities to sort the values.But before sorting float values we need to convert the values to float using the parseFloat() javavscript function .

http://hubpages.com/technology/How-to-sort-table-content-filter-table-data-and-add-pagination-using-Angular-JS

Answer (score 0):

Changing your predicate to the following will also work:

```
<th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = '1*age'; reverse=!reverse">Age</a></th>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK code while converting array into json.
json_encode($anyarray,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);