# Orderby filter in angular.filter plugin doesn't seem to sort properly

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Angular Filter plugin to group the tr's in a table based on the "Row" parameter.

Below code constructs the Tr according to Row value

```
<tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data |groupBy: 'Row' | orderBy : 'Row'">
          <td ng-repeat="person in row">{{person.Row}}.{{person.Label}}</td>    
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

But the 10th  and 11th item appears in the 2nd and 3rd row instead.
How can I fix this ?

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/GaW4XsAwlDkFs61VXkOl?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orderBy` must be the last filter in the chaining (when you apply filter to the result of another filter).
But, `groupBy` return an object, and `orderBy` expect array as an argument.
So, you can do something like that:

**JS:**

```
$scope.groups = [
    { category: 'alpha', id: 2 },
    { category: 'beta',  id: 3 }, 
    { category: 'gamma', id: 0 },
    { category: 'alpha', id: 4 },
    { category: 'beta',  id: 5 }, 
    { category: 'gamma', id: 1 }
   ];
  // retrieves the min 'id' of a collection, used for the group ordering.
  // you can use Agile.js instead. e.g: _.min(arr, 'id') 
  $scope.min = function(arr) {
    return $filter('min')
      ($filter('map')(arr, 'id'));
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
 <ul ng-repeat="group in groups | groupBy:'category' | toArray:true | orderBy:min">
    <!-- print the group name -->
    <li>{{ group.$key }}</li>
    <!-- iterate over the group members and order each group by id -->
    <li ng-repeat="item in group | orderBy:'id'">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**RESULTS:**

- gamma

  - {"category":"gamma","id":0}
  - {"category":"gamma","id":1}
- alpha

  - {"category":"alpha","id":2}
  - {"category":"alpha","id":4}
- beta

  - {"category":"beta","id":3}
  - {"category":"beta","id":5}

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the row number gets treated as a String:

Look at these two posts:

[Angular orderBy number sorting as text in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764177/angular-orderby-number-sorting-as-text-in-ng-repeat)

[AngularJS orderby integer field not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175054/angularjs-orderby-integer-field-not-working-properly)

Comment: If that is the case then how come only row 10,11 gets affected ? Btw it's is already in integer format in json.

Comment: Apparently there is a problem with groupBy it overrules orderBy, for example if you group after Label it gets sorted after Label. If you do not use the groupBy the order is fine

Comment: in the code if I remove |groupBy: 'Row', nothing shows up in the td, it's empty

Comment: You have to edit the <td> as well:
`<tr ng-repeat="row in data | orderBy : 'Row'">
          <td >{{row.Row}}.{{row.Label}}</td>`