# Angular OrderBy index not functioning

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am setting the default orderby on a directive. On certain click events I'm changing the order by the column that was clicked upon. However when I try to set a default order by the index I get some really strange results.

I've created a Plunker based off the Angular Documentation. My goal is to have the default orderBy (only code shown here) perform no sorting so that I can change the orderBy property later.

Plunker: [Plunker Or HTML Below](http://plnkr.co/edit/tMe4A43thel06elQWznD?p=preview)

```
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <table class="friend">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>index</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'index'">
        <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
        <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{friends.indexOf(friend)}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

New [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WSVdJq7unEEElo9LBzzr?p=preview). It appears as if this is a change from Angular 1.2 to 1.3 I tested working code on different versions of angular and in 1.2 you can pass a empty order by and it will order by the index but in 1.3 and 1.4 it sorts differently

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS orderby integer field not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175054/angularjs-orderby-integer-field-not-working-properly)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. My question is different. My question is how can I get OrderBy to order by the index of the items in the array

Comment: The only reason I think it is a duplicate, is the index seems to be sorted as if it is a string. You will need to cast index as a number for orderBy to work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by presorting my list at all times.

Then my function did all the work I was previously relying on Angular to do for me.

As an FYI I also submitted this as a bug to the angularJS team. They reported that it will be fixed in the next release (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12100)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any sorting at all here, the array is already in the order you want it to be. Assuming that you have a variable `$scope.orderByField` defining which property you want to use for ordering you could do something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in (orderByField ? (friends | orderBy : orderByField) : friends)">
```

So you would use the orderBy filter only if you really need it.

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/kXOSF4adOohDDxLEtnGT?p=preview

---

Appart from that you can also define a custom comparator method and use it:

```
$scope.sortByIndex = function(a, b) {
  return $scope.friends.indexOf(a) - $scope.friends.indexOf(b)
}

<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy : sortByIndex">
```

But i wouldn't really recommend to use that, cause you will do unnecessary calculations.

Comment: Correct. In this example I don't need sorting, I did that for simplicity. In my application I do need sorting but I want it to initialize the sort to display items in their order.

Comment: @TheMcMurder Yeah, you would get that by the first solution. It will use the orderBy filter if an orderByField is defined, if not the filter will not be used and you have the items in their initial order.

Comment: Added a plunker for the first solution, including a select menu to select the order by column.

Comment: The inline conditional idea is good. Unfortunately it only works in some cases. If you need to use the reverse param it no longer works.

Angular Documentation (  
    {{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : expression : reverse}}  
)